# easy to understand guide/tutorial explaining gwt 2 and MVP framework

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Can you point me to a good guide/how to that clearly explains how to use the MVP Framework in GWT? I tried using the latest version of GWT- ver 2.4 to create a sample app and many of the things in the sample app were new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at MVP4G. (Google it.) The event model is slightly different, that is, "places and activities" are special types of events called navigation events. I started a project with it 3 months ago, and have found it quite productive. Once you get beyond the basics of how to define and implement views and presenters, injecting services, and maybe even using GWT's UiBinder feature, you'll probably spend more time going down rabbit holes with GWT component API.

Comment: hello crhis... can you also tell me where to read about the main components of MVP, namely- Event Bus, Dependency Injection, Model View Presenter and Place Service? Thanks

Comment: Go view Ray Ryan's famous talk at Google I/o 2009 on YouTube, here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEMQtwIwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPDuhR18-EdM&ei=P3BAT5egG8GiiQL5-ZG3AQ&usg=AFQjCNGWHE4_x61W_hjH_puskdY_HaKSeA

Comment: As for Place Service, if you don't go all-in w/ MVP4G, checkout this tutorial:  http://webcentersuite.blogspot.com/2011/08/gwt-development-with-activities-and.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

@Arvind the best GWT and MVP resource I've found is [Essential GWT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321705149) from Federico Kereki.  I've bought it for each of my GWT developers and we use it as a shared reference for the correct way to handle MVP.

Personally it would take a lot for me to move from MVP to MVP4G.  With 'native' MVP there's always the chance that either GWT itself, or the GWT Eclipse plugin may provide elevated support for it in the future.  Plus, you're more like to find a developer (or online support) for native MVP.